# Load Custom_post_type categories post with ajax

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, ajax

I am trying to load custom category post of custom_post_type using Ajax.

I have taken help from 
[Load categories with ajax](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190655/load-categories-with-ajax#)

The content is loading properly for default categories but not for my custom_post_type Category.

I have made little change in function for custom post_type:

```
$args = array (
        'cat' => $cat_id,
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'collections'
      );
```

Please help me to load custom post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "custom_post_type Category" and the custom post type is not related to categories by default.

To understand it you need to visualize it like this: the WordPress default **post type** is called `post` and the default **taxonomy** is called `category`. and they are related by default in WordPress core.
I am mentioning this because in your query you use the `cat` parameter which will search for the default `category` which isn't linked to your custom post type.

You could link them like this after you register your custom post type:

`register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'collections' );`

I can't recommend you the above since is harder to manage and creates weird logics.

My recommendation: if you create a custom post type(`collections`) you need to [register a new taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)(maybe called `collections_category`) and link it to your `collections`. Then you could query like this:

```
$args = array (
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'collections',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'collections_category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( $cat_id ),
        ),
    ),
  );
```